# How do I prove that finitely generated group with $g^2=1$ is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.

Assume for all $g\in G, g^2=e$.

Then, how do I show that $G$ is actually finite?

I don't know where to start..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show first that it is abelian and then use the [classification theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group). You will get that $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ for some natural number $n$.

*Edit:* Use of the classification theorem is not necessary as pointed out in the comment below, since $G$ abelian implies that for $n$ generators we can have at most $2^n$ elements (every possibility of multiplying the generators amongst eachother, as soon as we use one twice, it becomes the identity).

Comment: The classification theorem is maybe too big a gun for this. Once $G$ is shown to be abelian, one readily sees that $n$ generators can produce at most $2^n$ elements.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Agreed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that $G$ is abelian. Once you show that, then if $g_1,...,g_n$ are the generators, every element of $G$ is of the form $g_1^{a_1}...g_n^{a_n}$.

Since each
$g_i$ is of finite order there are finitely many distinct words of this form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb K=\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$. And define $\Bbb K\times G\to G$ by $(k,g)\mapsto g^k$.
Hence $G$ is a $\Bbb K$ vector space with finite dimension . so $G$ is finite.